# How to display a text only once within an xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML with "Drivers" node which can have  multiple "Driver" nodes as children. 
(/Motor/Drivers/Driver)
Each "Driver" has a childnode "Accident" which can have a value either Y or N.

Now I have an xsl to convert this xml to PDF using Apache FOP. 
And I have a requirement like: if any of the "Driver" node has Accident="Y", I want to display a text. Even if there are multiple "Driver" nodes with Accident="Y", I want the text to appear only once.

If I'm writing an xsl:for-each loop to loop through the Driver nodes and check the accident values, the text will appear each time Accident=Y. But I want the text to appear only once if Accident=Y for any of the Driver.

Without a break feature or changing value of a variable feature, How do I do this?

At runtime, xml can contain any number of Driver nodes within Drivers.

```
<Motor>
  <Drivers>
    <Driver>
      <Accident>
        <Value>Y</Value>
      </Accident>
    </Driver>
    <Driver>
      <Accident>
        <Value>Y</Value>
      </Accident>
    </Driver>
    <Driver>
      <Accident>
        <Value>N</Value>
      </Accident>
    </Driver>
    <Driver>
      <Accident>
        <Value>Y</Value>
      </Accident>
    </Driver>
  </Drivers>
</Motor>
```

Snapshot from Current XSL file :

```
<xsl:template name="DriverScedule">
<fo:block>
Some Block of existing text
</fo:block>
---Now I have to display another noew block of test here based on the condition---
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please post relevant portion of your XSL, so that we have a concrete context to suggest a concrete solution

Comment: `/Motor/Drivers/Driver[Accident='Y'][1]`

Comment: What else are doing inside your loop, which nine times out of ten is a code smell?

Comment: @torazaburo , In the XSL file, I'm just displaying some text based on the condition I told. If Accident Value is Y for one or more drivers, I want the text to be displayed just once.

Comment: What is your attempt, check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Still this isn't clear until you post relevant portion of your XSL, f.e what if you simply add the text from outside for-each?

Comment: I havn't written the xsl condition yet. I have an existing XML with lots of data, and an existing XSL file which processes it. Now I'm supposed to add a new condition within the xsl and check the condition I mentioned in the question and simply display a text within that condition.

Comment: @har07, question updated. Can you understand now?

Comment: You _still_ haven't shown us any XSLT code...

Comment: @PraveeshP Then why `xsl:for-each`, how about simple `xsl:if`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256212%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The existing xslt code has nothing to do with this logic and is a long xsl file with some other data. Current requirement is to write xsl logic to implement the scenario I told. I'm talking about the xsl for loop logic which can be used to implement this scenario.

Comment: @har07, xsl:for-each to loop through each "Driver" and check the Accident value.

Comment: And do what based on Accident value? Only to display text as asked in this question? That can be done using `xsl:if` to avoid repetition

Comment: @har07, I just want to display a block of text based on the given condition. How do I do that just with 'xsl:if' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Policy>
      <Risks>
        <Risk>
            <Motor>
                <Vehicle>
                    <VehicleCondition>
                        <HasProblemsMakingItUnsafe>
                            <Value>true</Value>
                        </HasProblemsMakingItUnsafe>
                    </VehicleCondition>
                </Vehicle>
            </Motor>
        </Risk>
        <Risk>
            <Motor>
                <Vehicle>
                    <VehicleCondition>
                        <HasProblemsMakingItUnsafe>
                            <Value>true</Value>
                        </HasProblemsMakingItUnsafe>
                    </VehicleCondition>
                </Vehicle>
            </Motor>
        </Risk>
        <Risk>
            <Motor>
                <Vehicle>
                    <VehicleCondition>
                        <HasProblemsMakingItUnsafe>
                            <Value>false</Value>
                        </HasProblemsMakingItUnsafe>
                    </VehicleCondition>
                </Vehicle>
            </Motor>
        </Risk>
      </Risks>
    </Policy>
```

I used below XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>

<xsl:if test="(/Policy/Risks/Risk/Motor/Vehicle/VehicleCondition/HasProblemsMakingItUnsafe/Value='false')">
<p>Hello</p>
</xsl:if>

  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And got output as:

```
Hello
```

So xsl:if actually iterates within the nodes to check if any of the node satisfies the condition.

Comment: can be tested here : http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_if

Answer (score 0):

`xsl:if` seems to be better suited for this task rather than `xsl:for-each`, for example :

```
<xsl:if test="//Driver/Accident/Value='Y'">
<!--`if test pass, print text "Foo" -->
    Foo
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: xpath is /Motor/Drivers/Driver , and there can be multiple Driver nodes. In that case if we just give <xsl:if test="/Motor/Drivers/Driver='Y'"> ,  will it check all the Driver nodes for Accident value = Y ?